# django server not displaying and not stopping

Tags: django, server

I have just started to use django and have followed a tutorial to simply create a project called 'mysite' and then created an app 'hello', which displays a hello world message. 
The web application works fine and is working as expected. However, I have been encountering a problem where

1. the terminal does not display the url and other things that should be displayed
2. the server does not shut down.

The terminal should display:
'Performing system checks...starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8080/ Quit the server with CONTROL-C.'

but instead, it displays nothing.

(I have found the $ sign does not exist anymore so assumed the server was working, and thankfully the server was running since the application was working on http://127.0.0.1:8080 as expected. Also, if I refresh the page, I get a response of '[02/Sep/2018 12:13:28] "GET/HTTP/1.1" 200 13' in my terminal which also indicates that the server is running)

Although I think it isn't a problem in my working process, I just don't understand why the terminal is not displaying anything. Is this a problem with my terminal or shell (I used zsh on a cygwin terminal on windows) or a problem with the setting with django (am I missing an installation or something)?

Second and more problematic, is that the server does not seem to shut down even with CTRL-C. 
I have used CTRL-C multiple times after the server is running. But it just does not seem to shut down. The terminal gives me an X to indicate that the CTRL-C command did not work (a custom configuration into my zsh theme) and when I refresh the page it still outputs out a response of '[02/Sep/2018 12:13:28] "GET/HTTP/1.1" 200 13'.

The server just does not stop. Even when I close the cygwin terminal and open http://127.0.0.1:8080 on another browser, it still runs the application. No matter what I do, the server just does not shut off. I am really confused.

This seems like such a simple problem but I haven't been able to find any answers to why this is happening and how to solve it.

Thanks in advance for any help and advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the process running on port 8080 here.

Run the following command to find the number process identification number(PID):

```
sudo lsof -t -i:8080
```

- **sudo** - command to ask admin privilege.
- **lsof** - list related processes or list files
- **-t** - show only process ID
- **-i** - show only internet connections related process
- **:8080** - show only processes in this port number

Kill the process from PID using following command:

```
sudo kill -9 <PID>
```

Here,

- **kill** - command to kill the process
- **-9** - forcefully

As a single command you can use :

```
sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:8080)
```